# In Rails 3 how to create a layout that includes css that is only used by a certain view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a view called admin and I want to use a css file admin.css that is being used only in this page.
I created a new layout admin.html.erb in layouts. What do I put in there and how do I edit application.css so that admin.css is only being used in the admin view but every other stylesheet is included in admin view as well?

Thank you!
This is what I have in application.css so far

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per   style scope.
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require custom
 *= require admin
 *= require_self
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't `require admin` in your `application.css`, else you would end including the content of this file in your processed css file.

Leave `admin.css` as it is (this file will hold all your admin css resource, you can even reference other files if you need it), remove the `require admin` line from `application.css`, and add the following in your `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.css']
```

This will instruct the assets pipeline to precompile `admin.css` as a separate file.

Then in your admin layout include both:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin" %>
```

And in your non-admin layout just include application.

Comment: thanks, I did exactly this but it didn't work. my admin view didn't include the application.css